# Creating custom annotation using Spring @Prefilter with own method and parameters

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-el

I would like to create own annotation, that will be used to disable chosen feature. It will take FeatureName String as a parameter, and based on boolean that is stored in db, if its disabled, it will throw exception when using method, or do nothing in feature is enabled.
Code of how should it look like:

Lets say that i want to disable one controller method, usage:

```
@FeatureFlag(featureName = "Invoices")
@GetMapping
Set<InvoiceDTO> getAllInvoices() {
    return InvoiceService.getAllInvoices();
}
```

Annotation class:

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
@PreAuthorize("@featureService.isEnabled(#featureName)")
public @interface FeatureFlag {
    String featureName() default "" ;
}
```

and the method that is called by `@PreAuthorize`:

```
@Service
class FeatureService {

    private final FeatureRepository featureRepository;

    public FeatureService(FeatureRepository featureRepository) {
        this.featureRepository = featureRepository;
    }

    void isEnabled(String featureName) {
        boolean isEnabled = featureRepository.getByName(featureName);

        if (!isEnabled) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This functionality is disabled, it cannot be used");
        }
    }
}
```

When accessing endpoint from controller, the `isEnabled` method from `FeatureService` is called, but `featureName` String is null instead of ,,Invoices". I have tried many ways to pass this argument but none of them work, is there any way to do this?